# Add/Insert data using repository MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently being taught how to use MVC and my supervisor showed me how to use a repository with a read function but I'm stuck with implementing an Add function. This is my current code, thanks in advance!

Repository:

```
    public void AddDriver(DriverModel model)
    {
        using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
        {
            var newDriver = new Driver();

            newDriver.DriverLastName = model.DriverLastName;
            newDriver.DriverFirstName = model.DriverFirstName;
            newDriver.DriverLicense = model.DriverLicense;
            newDriver.LicenseExpiry = model.LicenseExpiry;
            newDriver.MobileNumber = model.MobileNumber;
            newDriver.BusinessUnit = model.BusinessUnit;
            newDriver.DateRegistered = model.DateRegistered;

            db.Driver.Add(newDriver);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var repo = new VehicleRepository();
        var data = repo.AddDriver();
        var DVM = new DriverViewModel();

        DVM.DriverLastName = data.DriverLastName;
        DVM.DriverFirstName = data.DriverFirstName;
        DVM.DriverLicense = data.DriverLicense;
        DVM.LicenseExpiry = data.LicenseExpiry;
        DVM.MobileNumber = data.MobileNumber;
        DVM.BusinessUnit = data.BusinessUnit;
        DVM.DateRegistered = data.DateRegistered;

        db.Driver.Add();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: In the controller, I get an error that I can't use void to assign to an implicit value. I'm not entirely sure what the next set of codes I should use.

Comment: In the controller you should call `AddDriver(DVM)`

Comment: Your code seems a bit off.. the Repository's responsibility is to add a `DriverModel` object to the `Driver` table in your database.  Then in your controller, it seems you're trying to retrieve a `Driver` object from the Repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a few issues with what you've posted. I think you're looking for something like the following:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActonResult Add(DriverViewModel DVM)
{
    var repo = new VehicleRepository();

    var driver = new Driver();

    //tools such as automapper or tinymapper are often used so that you dont
    //need to manually make these assignments
    driver.DriverLastName = DVM.DriverLastName;
    driver.DriverFirstName = DVM.DriverFirstName;
    driver.DriverLicense = DVM.DriverLicense;
    driver.LicenseExpiry = DVM.LicenseExpiry;
    driver.MobileNumber = DVM.MobileNumber;
    driver.BusinessUnit = DVM.BusinessUnit;
    driver.DateRegistered = DVM.DateRegistered;

    repo.AddDriver(driver);

    //return whatever view you want to go to after the save
    return View("Index");
}
```

Repository:

```
public void AddDriver(Driver newDriver)
{
    using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
    {
        db.Driver.Add(newDriver);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

a few notes: normally, if you're using viewmodels then these viewmodels are posted to the controller instead of the raw EF entities. You were also calling `db.SaveChanges` in the controller as well as the repository which doesn't seem like what you want. `DbSet`s are also normally pluralized so your call to add the driver to the db would look like `db.Drivers.Add(newDriver)`. You've also shown 3 different classes related to Drivers: `Driver`, `DriverModel` and `DriverViewModel`. Sometimes this is necessary if your architecture has things separated out into multiple different layers for data access, business logic, and web however I don't see any evidence of that here. If everything exists in one project, I'd probably stick to `DriverViewModel` and `Driver` where `Driver` is the EF entity and `DriverViewModel` is what your views use and pass back to the controller

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, this really helped! Though now I'm more conflicted now because my senior was apparently teaching me the wrong way. Anyways, does this work the same when inserting to multiple tables?

Comment: @Joshua you can make your repository methods do anything you'd like . Generally, we strive to keep them as simple as possible and only have DB related work in them (any CRUD operations). And it's hard to say whether someone is teaching you the "wrong" way by the code shown. Also, if you're starting to do work on a large, pre-existing application then its better (imo) to stick with the scheme that already exists than it is to start implementing things in different ways.